# What is the motivation behind the inverse Weibull distribution

Tags: distributions, weibull-distribution

It seems like both the Weibull and the inverse or reversed Weibull model failure rates, waiting times and extreme phenomena.

The inverse Weibull pdf is

$$f_X(x; \alpha, \beta) = \beta \alpha^{-\beta}x^{-\beta - 1}\exp\left[- (\alpha x)^{-\beta} \right], \quad\quad x\geq 0, \alpha> 0, \beta >0$$

with $\alpha =\text{ scale}, \quad \beta =\text{ shape}.$

and is used in reliability, ecology, branching processes and medicine according to [this](https://digitalcommons.georgiasouthern.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2192&context=etd).

The Weibull pdf is

$$f_X(x; \lambda, k) = \frac k\lambda \left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^{k-1}\; \exp\left[-\left(\frac x\lambda\right)^k\right]\quad\quad x\geq0, \lambda \in (0,\infty), k \in (0,\infty)$$

with $\lambda = \text{ scale}; \quad k =\text{ shape}$

and it is used in survival analysis, reliability engineering, extreme value theory, weather forecasting , wind power, insurance, according to Wikipedia.

At a basic level they both are valid distributions, integrating to $1,$ and there is no more to be said. However, there must have been a need to invert the sign in the exponent in the exponential part to construct a different distribution out of the Weibull to serve some modelling needs.

What is the motivation behind these two "versions" of the Weibull? What are their differential uses?

Comment: @AdamO They're not simply reparameterizations of each other. The form of the first is what you get when you do a transformation $Y=1/X$ where $X\sim\text{Weibull}$. It's like the relationship between the gamma distribution and the inverse-gamma distribution, for example.

Comment: @Glen_b Shouldn't then the sign within $\exp()$ change?

Comment: The sign on the power inside $\exp()$ should change (because we go from $x$ to $y^{-1}$), but the sign of the whole term inside the $(\,)$ should not.

Comment: @Glen_b I just read that inverse Weibull = Fréchet. If this is true, then that's the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution

Comment: 1. It's not 'the answer' to the posed question, since "it's Fréchet" is not an answer to the question "what is the *motivation*?"; it's substituting one name for another. The name is not the thing and doesn't of itself motivate anything $-$ that could only work if we assumed you already had a motivation for the Fréchet but I see no reason to assume that (indeed, there's reason to assume you'd never heard of the  Fréchet, or you'd presumably have recognized it). $\:$ 2. This distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution is inverse-Weibull, ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... *if you add a shift parameter* to the inverse Weibull. This addition is not in your parameterization.

Comment: @Glen_b Once identified with the Fréchet the path is clear: it's one of the three generalized extreme value distributions with Gumbel and Weibull. Not an easy topic by any means, but plenty of information on it.

Comment: @Glen_b In deference to the truth, your statement "indeed, there's reason to assume you'd never heard of the Fréchet" is incorrect. I have run many simulations of extreme values from datasets such as the financial markets, and fitted different EV distributions to them. This has been a hobby over several years now. I am obviously no expert, but you diminish yourself berating online a complete stranger to you, and assuming things without any basis. How are the ad hominem statements in your comment of any use or edifying purpose? Think about it.

Comment: There is a big difference between asking for the level of familiarity with a topic on the part of the asker to provide an answer that is understandable, and to pass gratuitous statements without any constructive elements. Even some experts, perhaps not of your caliber, can be confused by the multiple parameterization options in these distributions. But who cares if I have familiarity or not with the Frechet? Or if you think that there is reason to believe I am not?

Comment: The point is whether you feel some idiots like myself could benefit from an answer at our level to the question, or you just want to be acclaimed by the choir of cognoscenti with a snarky comment. It is small - as in extreme value small.

Comment: The fact that you happen to be familar with the Frechet is beside the point I made which was what there was reason to assume so from the information in the question. Whether you have it or not isn't at issue (you seem to have read some kind of insult where there literally was none), but whether "It's the Frechet" is a reasonable answer to the posted question. I maintain it is not inherently any more an answer than "it's the inverse Weibull". You placed your personal knowledge of it  into the discussion, not me, though readers had no way to infer that you'd feel it would suffice for an answer.

Comment: ... until you said so. I still don't think it's a good answer for the wider readership, who indeed may not have heard of it. If you do believe it's a suitable answer, please post it.

Comment: @Glen_b Instead of all this pedantic splitting hairs you could have posted a formal answer. Ask yourself what you are compensating for with all this non sense about the answer or the reason to speculate. Do you realize how petty you sound?